# Run part of command line command with sudo

Tags: sudo, users, non-root-user, privileges

I execute this

```
time sudo nice -n -20 bash myscript.sh
```

myscript.sh then processes some files as well as create files with the result.

Two problems with this:

- the script is run as root
- the resulting files are owned by root

I don't want the script to run with root privileges (in case I made a mistake in it and it starts to delete important stuff etc) and the output should be owned by me.

**I need sudo to change the priority of the script but how do I run the script as my regular user?**

Comment: IIRC, `nice` only applies to the single process. In which case, the niceness would not be inherited by any child command your shell executes. If you have a shell script which is complex enough to benefit from `nice`, it would benefit by orders of magnitude by rewriting in a real language. You might benchmark your script with and without niceness, and see what difference it makes (maybe in a VM if you think it might misbehave).

Comment: You might consider `renice`. This would let you (from a separate terminal) become sudo, and change the niceness of specific pids, a whole process group, or all processes owned by a user. (It is not clear whether `renice` affects future processes started by that user, or only those which were already running when `renice -u user` was issued.)

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, niceness is inherited by children, `nice sh -c 'ps; exit'` shows `sh` and `ps` share the same niceness.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I am executing a C++ binary on many files. The script is short, basically a wrapper that loops over the files and feeds them into the binary. This loop takes days to finish. It is the binary I want to run with minimum niceness, the script doesn't matter. Are you sure about the inheritance? I did some benchmarking and got some 10-20 % improvement when changing the priority, but it could be a coincidence (e.g., less other tasks running on the computer when I benchmarked).

Comment: I'm not sure a 20% improvement on "days" is your best shot. Can you use `parallel`, or a radical rethink of the algorithms?  Can you profile the code to find hot-spots? I once got a script down from 30 days to 100 seconds (granted, the original was awful).

Comment: What is parallel? I run six instances of the script in parallel (if I run more I run out of memory and is I/O-limited).

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to switch uids and gids back. You can use `zsh` for that where assigning to `$USERNAME` changes all uid, euid, gids etc to those of the corresponding user as if that user had just logged in without making any other changes.

```
sudo nice -n -20 zsh -c 'USERNAME=$SUDO_USER; exec bash ./myscript.sh'
```

Or:

```
sudo nice -n -20 su "$LOGNAME" -c 'exec bash ./myscript.sh'
```

Or:

```
sudo nice -n -20 sudo -u "$LOGNAME" bash ./myscript.sh
```

Though note that those involve going through the PAM stack another time and could do extra changes to the environment (which may or may not be desirable) including resetting the niceness.

In any case, you could end up with a different set of gids if those you had beforehand were not the ones from the user database.

To reset the list as it were, another option is to pass it around with the help of `perl` for instance which has the same `$UID`, `$GID`, `$EGID` variables as `zsh` (with `-MEnglish`) except the the gid ones also have information about the supplementary gids (and can also do the `nice` by itself):

```
run_with_nice() (
  exec perl -MEnglish -e '
    exec qw(sudo perl -MEnglish -MPOSIX=nice -e), qq(
    nice(shift\@ARGV);
    \$GID = "$GID"; \$EGID = "$EGID"; \$UID = $UID; \$EUID = $EUID;
    exec \@ARGV), "--", @ARGV' -- "$@"
)
```

Then run:

```
$ run_with_nice -20 ps -o pid,user,group,nice,args
    PID USER     GROUP     NI COMMAND
   6955 chazelas chazelas -20 ps -o pid,user,group,nice,args
```

Or in your case:

```
run_with_nice -20 bash ./myscript.sh
```

Another approach in this case where the point is to change the niceness is to use `renice` instead, though beware the handling of its arguments is very unportable (and often don't work as documented in my experience) with some treating the number as an increment, some as the new value:

```
sh -c 'sudo renice -n -20 -p "$$" && exec bash ./myscript.sh'
```

Would change the niceness of the process running `sh` and then carry on running `bash` in the same process, without ever changing the uids/gids or the `sh` process. Here [with the `renice` from util-linux 2.38.1, that *sets* the niceness to `-20` instead of decrementing it by 20](https://marc.info/?l=util-linux-ng&m=156846960629603&w=2) like `nice -n` or `nice()` do.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the niceness of the script in user mode with `sudo renice`, which should change that of the script and of any child processes it subsequently creates (thanks to @StéphaneChazelas for correcting me on this).

Note the `-g` (process group) option to `renice`. As the script is already running, we need to also apply the niceness to any C++ child process that may have already been started.

```
$ cat nicely
#! /bin/bash

for (( j = 0; j < 10; j++ )); do
    printf 'Pid %d nice %d\n' $$ $( nice )
    sleep 3
done

$ ./nicely & Pid=$!; sudo renice -n -14 -g "${Pid}"; wait
[1] 5665
Pid 5665 nice 0
[sudo] password for paul: Pid 5665 nice 0
Pid 5665 nice 0
*******Pid 5665 nice 0
 
5665 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority -14
Pid 5665 nice -14
...
Pid 5665 nice -14
[1]+  Done                    ./nicely
paul@paul-RV415-RV515 ~ $
```

Comment: `$!` is not guaranteed to match the process group number of the job. You can also use `renice` before running the command as shown at the end of my answer.